# Classic ASP - How to convert a UTF-8 string to UTF-16?

Tags: asp-classic, kannel

I know there is already have post: [Classic ASP - How to convert a UTF-8 string  to UCS-2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916118/classic-asp-how-to-convert-a-utf-8-string-to-ucs-2)

But my situation another.
I want convert UTF-8 to UCS-2BE.
For example this text in UTF-8 "Мухтарам Мизоч" convert to this "CEB0@0<� 87>G".

For example in PHP i can use ready function `iconv("utf-8","ucs-2be","Мухтарам Мизоч");`
But in classical ASP can't find any solution.
This solution need for send Unicode SMS text via Kannel.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, like you the OP was trying to send to an SMS Provider - [Answer to convert utf-8 to iso-8859-1 in classic asp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17680939/692942).

Comment: The difference is your passing in `UTF-8` and want to output `UTF-16` (supersedes `UCS-2`) the process is identical.

Comment: I've dug into this a bit more as I'm not familiar with the Kannel SMS Gateway. What version are you using? Looking at the [user guide](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.3/userguide-1.4.3/userguide.html) suggests that [by default the `coding` parameter is set to 7 bits](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.3/userguide-1.4.3/userguide.html#AEN4322) when using the `sendsms` cgi script so you should be able to send `UTF-8` is it possible to update your question and add some code that shows you trying to send the message to the `sendsms` cgi script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So sick of answering this question, but I feel impelled to as you have made a common assumption that many make when it comes to encoding in ASP, PHP or whatever language you are using.

> In web development encoding is intrinsically linked to
>
> **The source encoding you use to save the web page**

Just looking at the comments under the [iconv reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) made me laugh and sad at the same time because there are so many people out there who don't understand this topic.

Take for example your PHP snippet

```
iconv("utf-8","ucs-2be","Мухтарам Мизоч");
```

This will work providing the following is true

- The page author saved the file using `UTF-8` encoding (Most modern editors have this option in some shape or form).
- The client Internet Browser knows it should be handling the page as `UTF-8` either via a meta tag in the HTML,

  ```html
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  ```

  or by specifying a HTTP Content-Type Header

---

In terms of Classic ASP it is the same you need to;

- Make sure the page is saved as `UTF-8` encoding, this includes any `#include` files that are dependencies.
- Tell IIS that your pages are `UTF-8` by specifying this pre-processing instruction at the very top of the page (must be the first line).

  ```vb
  <%@Language="VBScript" CodePage = 65001 %>
  ```
- Tell the browser what encoding you are using

  ```vb
  <%
  'Tell server to send all strings back to the client as UTF-8
  'while also setting the charset in the HTTP Content Type header.
  Responce.CodePage = 65001
  Response.ContentType = "html/text"
  Response.Charset = "UTF-8"
  %>
  ```

---

**UPDATE:**

Neither `UCS-2` (`UTF-16` LE) or `UCS-2BE` (`UTF-16` BE) are supported by Classic ASP, specifying either `CodePage` (1200 or 1201) will result in;

```
ASP 0203 - Invalid CodePage Value
```

After reading a bit about Kannel it does appear as though you can control the character set you send to the SMS gateway, I would recommend you try to send it using `UTF-8`.

**Links**

- [Sending arabic SMS in kannel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10194047/692942) (This question is about sending arabic SMS using Java to Kannel but the information is relevant).
- [Unicode on Windows XP](http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-13410.html) (Although aimed at Windows XP the codepage information is still relevant).

Comment: I think doing it right, but i'm get in UTF-16 "믯킿톜톃톅킂톰킀킰₼鳐룐럐뻐蟑" in PHP i get "CEB0@0<� 87>G". May be UTF-16 and UCS-2be not same?

Comment: You maybe right, as `UTF-16` does not supersede `UCS-2BE` (big endian) it's supersedes `UCS-2`. What's more neither are supported in IIS / Classic ASP, if you try to set them you will get `ASP 0203 - Invalid CodePage Value`. You need to configure Kannel to send using `UTF-8` which from what I have read it is more then capable of doing.

Comment: Yes, i'm decide my problem with setting in Kannel "coding=UTF-8".

Answer (score 0):

in kannel.conf in section SMSC add alt-charset = UCS-2 (or UCS-2BE) thats enough. Kannel  well send to smsc in this charset.